# Grab/Use cookie in Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scraping data in this website
: https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_cookie/
but the data is stored in
this url : https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/ajaxdetail_cookie/?token=YQ00FY4B4D

The token changes at each visit

I don't know how to extract data from the 2nd url

[image: requests]

```
import json


class FindgoldSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'findgold'

    def start_requests(self):
        url='https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/ajaxdetail_cookie/?token='
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
            'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest' ,
        }
        cookies = {
            '__cfduid' : 'd6ec4f3842fa1b47ec88a035af6773fd11599773899' ,
        }
        yield scrapy.http.Request(url, headers=headers)
    
    def parse(self, response):
        data = response.json
        print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you if i do not understand wrong. try to help.

```
import scrapy
import json
from ..items import JsonscrapyItem
class PatelcoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'patelco'
    allowed_domains = ['patelco.org']
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_cookie/']

def start_requests(self):
    headers = {
        'authority': 'scrapingclub.com',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36',
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'referer': 'https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_cookie/',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'cookie': '__cfduid=dadbc0660498959aca2ad988813bede171600011839; _ga=GA1.2.1127524216.1600011846; _gid=GA1.2.685369613.1600011846; _gat_gtag_UA_39890589_8=1; token=14Z022XFYS',
    }

    params = (
        ('token', '14Z022XFYS'),
    )

    yield scrapy.Request(url=self.start_urls[0], meta={'data': params}, headers=headers, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):

    hreflink = response.xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/p[1]/a/@href').extract()
    data = response.xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/p[2]/text()').extract()


    print('\n',hreflink, '\n')
    print('\n',data, '\n')
```